# Columns are lost after using groupby().sum() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I am working on grouping some data together by a certain column name and sum all the values.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('Data_Cleaning.xlsx', sheetname='Expenses reclassification')

data.columns = data.iloc[1,:]
data = data.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5])
data = data.set_index('ALL NUMBERS EXPRESSED IN SGD')
data = data.groupby(level = 0).sum()
print(data.head())
```

Before I grouped the data the dataframe has shape (103,117) and after grouping the returning dataframe has shape (68,36). A lot of the columns are lost. All the columns should be numerical values.

My question is what has happened and is there any way that Python can return say (68,117) dataframe back to me. Thanks!

Comment: most likely some of these columns end up being not numeric.

Comment: @MK. Hi MK. I just checked after seeing your comment with data.dtypes, seems like the latter data are object rather than float64, is there anyway I can fix that? The original data should be numbers in excel. Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html ?

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation function, a sum in this case, will be performed on the columns which support such aggregation, i.e. numerical columns. It seems you have just 36 numerical columns.

If you think there should be more numerical columns, you may want to check types of each column, and if you sense something's wrong, you may need to check for anomalies in the data.

Hope this helps!